# Add some element in CustomView (which is in fragment)

Tags: android, android-custom-view

This sound simple and probably answer is trivial.

I have `SomeCustomView` class which extending `RelativeView`. This `SomeCustomView` have simple `addShapeInCustomView()`:

```
public class SomeCustomView extends RelativeLayout {

    //constructor etc.
    public void addShapeInCustomView(){
        View testView = new View(ctx);
        testView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(50, viewHeight));
        ViewHelper.setTranslationX(testView, 20);
        testView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        addView(testView);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Of course I added this in my xml layout:

```
<com.example.test.app.lib.SomeCustomView
   android:id="@+id/someCustomView"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:layout_margin="5dp"
   android:background="@color/darkblue">
```

Then in Fragment I calling `addShapeInCustomView()`:

```
public View onCreateView(...){
    //inflate etc.
    someCustomView = (SomeCustomView) view.findViewById(R.id.someCustomView);
    someCustomView.addShapeInCustomView();
}
```

`SomeCustomView` is creating correctly. No errors. But testView from `addShapeInCustomView()` isn't visible.

**What am I doing wrong?** What if I want add some elements after initialization (and after `onDraw())`? I should call `addShapeInCustomView()` in other moment of `Fragment` lifecycle (tested and nothing happens)?

**If I call `addShapeInCustomView()` with 200ms of delay it's works perfectly**. someView shows up. But obviously it's strange work around.

Comment: try to call invalidate() to force your view re-draw?

Comment: I'm calling it on addShapeInCustomView method(last line).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `requestLayout()` in place of `invalidate()`. Invalidating just redraws the current layout, whereas `requestLayout()` will re-measure and layout the child views, then draw them.

Comment: Nope. Still nothing. Should I @Override onLayout method?